# Why page is shown after POST request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

Sorry for the weird title. I have the following code that tests the post() function of jquery:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {

        $("form#f").submit(function(){
            var result = "";
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: "test.php",
                dataType: "script",
                success: function(data){
                    result = data;
                }
            });
            alert(result);
        });

     }

</script>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="test.php" id="f">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

... and this is the test.php implementation:

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    echo "hello " . $_POST['name'];
?>
```

Why is the page shown instead of data appearing in the alert dialog in submit() function? Sorry I know that this is a n00b question. I'm not really good at Javascript.

Comment: Try adding `return false;`  at the end of the function you assign to the submit action.  I believe this will override the default behaviour which is to actually submit the form to the action url.

Comment: change your `<input type='submit'/>` to `<input type='button'/>`

Answer (score 2):

do `return false;` at the end of your submit handler. Otherwise you are not preventing the normal submit (post to test.php) to occur

```
$("form#f").submit(function(){
            var result = "";
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: "test.php",
                dataType: "script",
                success: function(data){
                    result = data;
                    alert(result);  // And move that here
                }
            });
            return false;  // Here

        });
```

Comment: Dude!  You so stole your answer from my comment!  Just Kidding :-P +1

Comment: @Endophage. Ha ha... i think you're misunderstanding how SO works :)

Comment: @Jairo. What "doesn't work"? is it still posting the form, or do you get an error in your JS console?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to returning false is to use jQuery's [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):

```
    $("form#f").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // do stuff
    });
```

Comment: I assume the reason this didn't work is that it didn't also move the `alert` into the success callback. `event.preventDefault` is a better solution than `return false` though, since it still cancels the event if there are uncaught errors in the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

@Jairo I tried your original code and it worked using the CDN.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```